# Getting the CPU usage generates "Category does not exist" error

Tags: c#

I'm using the flowing code, but it says that category does not exist.

```
static PerformanceCounter cpuUsage;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    cpuUsage = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

    Console.WriteLine(cpuUsage.NextValue() + " %");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(cpuUsage.NextValue() + " %");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: If any one sure that this worked successfully please check this code and run in your pc thanks.

Comment: Can you screenshot your error and add it to your question?

Comment: Is it possible that the name of the performance counter is localized, and on your machine it should be given a localized version of "Processor"?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/10AeS.png

Comment: Update the question by providing more detailed information about the exception that is being generated. Copy the text and paste it in the question, screenshots cannot be that much helpful.

Comment: I solved it buddy.............
In this line of coe just change it by
 new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
 new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Its working fine at my end. Look at image.

[image]

Comment: I just solved it.....
PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

Comment: Why is this accepted? This is very low quality answer and not an actual answer. There is a reason why it sometimes works and sometimes does not, it is answered in a lower answer

Comment: This returns the entire CPU, which is not an answer

Answer (score 19):

Good afternoon!

The core cause of this problem is a seemingly random corruption of the pointers to the performance counters in the registry. This happens infrequently, but most often happens on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Strictly speaking the "Process" and "Processor" category should always exist by default as performance counters. If they are missing, there are possibly many other counters that are missing as well. The previous solutions would not solve the problem if the "Processor Information" counter was also corrupted as well. To resolve this definitively you can run the following command:

```
lodctr /R
```

This will repair any broken pointers to your counters. To verify this solution you can go to  Server Manager -> Monitoring -> Performance Monitor -> Add ... 
Within this view you can view all of the currently registered performance counters. Both "Processor" and "Process" should now be available. Alternatively, you can run the following command to view the status of all of the available counters as well:

```
lodctr /Q
```

As a side note, this command should be run from an Administrative console; otherwise this process may fail with "error code: 5 (Access Denied)"

Comment: Wow, I did not expect that, but your answer helped! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, lodctr /R worked for me, I encountered the same error when I used a third-party tool and found the error message in their log file.

Comment: Error while running lodctr /R as admin:  "Unable to rebuild performance counter setting from system backup store, error code is 2".   Happening on windows 10.  Hmm, the solution is just run it again though.  Shticks on silicon.

Comment: Which one is the Processor tough? I see no processor name

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
```

Instead of

```
new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
```

Comment: Why? What is the difference?

Comment: @m1o2, ["Processor" vs "Processor information"](https://superuser.com/questions/384554)

Comment: Used this
                m_processCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process Information", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
                m_totalCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

did not help me at all

Answer (score 2):

Check that the performance counter in question is enabled. I found a bunch of counters were disabled on some of our servers.

Here's some PowerShell to find disabled counters:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\*\Performance | 
    Where-Object { ($_ | Get-ItemProperty -Name 'Disable Performance Counters' -ea Ignore).'Disable Performance Counters' -eq 1 }
```

Here's the PowerShell we used to re-enable all our disabled counters:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\*\Performance | 
    Where-Object { ($_ | Get-ItemProperty -Name 'Disable Performance Counters' -ea Ignore).'Disable Performance Counters' -in @(0,1) } | 
    Remove-ItemProperty -Name 'Disable Performance Counters' -Verbose -WhatIf
```

I chose to delete the `Disable Performance Counters` key value instead of setting it to `0`, hence the `-in @(0,1)` clause above.

Some ASP.NET counters' `Disable Performance Counters` value were set to `4` or `2`. I left those alone.

Answer (score 2):

Being a bit more specific, you can check your Event Viewer and look for PerfLib events.

In my case, they were marked with errors.

Then, after looking around I found the two commands explained above.
In my case, the problem was with the perfOS. (you can always run `lodctr /q:Perflib` to check what's disabled.

Then, run:
lodctr /e:perfOS (or change perfOS for whatever service is disabled)

That will do (at least it worked for me)

TLDR: run `lodctr /q:perfOs` and `lodctr /e:perfOS` as Admin

Answer (score 1):

Use this static method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a65ekyd.aspx)):

```
PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories()
```

to retrieve an array of all categories registered on your machine. Perhaps `Processor` has been localized.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1305159/860585) SO answer for code that retrieves all counters.

Comment: PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

Comment: Yes its work.
 new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
Thanks to all