# How to see/debug System.Diagnostics Counter?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to see what all Performance Counter has been registered by an application?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304949/list-all-performance-counters-for-a-category

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check the [`GetCounter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew6c05xw.aspx) method from the `PerformanceCounterCategory` class. You will take a [`PerformanceCounter[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) and some information about for each counter.

```
PerformanceCounterCategory pcc = new PerformanceCounterCategory();

// Retrieves the list of performance object instances that are associated with this category.
foreach (string instanceName in pcc.GetInstanceNames()) 
    // Retrieves a list of the counters in a performance counter category that contains exactly one instance.
    foreach (PerformanceCounter counter in pcc.GetCounters())
    {
        // now you have the counter object that represents a PerformanceCounter to get some information about the performance counter

        Console.WriteLine("Category: " + counter.Category);
        Console.WriteLine("Instance Name: " + counter.InstanceName);    
        Console.WriteLine("Machine Name: " + counter.MachineName);

        Console.WriteLine("Counter Name: " + counter.CounterName);

        Console.WriteLine("Next Value: " + counter.NextValue());
    }
```