# Performance counters - get counter name list

Tags: c#, winforms, performancecounter

I have a small winforms app written in c# framework 4.0.
In my app i would like to provide the user a list of available counters under category "serviceModelService 4.0.0.0"
From where can I populate the list of counter name and instance name, like the PerformanceCounter control does?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all performance counters for a category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304949/list-all-performance-counters-for-a-category)