# C# InvalidOperationException when creating PerformanceCounter "NetworkInterface CurrentBandwidth *"

Tags: c#, performancecounter

When I try to create an instance of System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter class with the following parameters:

```
categoryName = NetworkInterface,  
counterName = CurrentBandwidth, 
instanceName = *.
```

I get an exception System.InvalidOperationException: Instance '*' does not exist in the specified Category.

I don't understand why star sign doesn't work for selecting all the instances in the category. In PerfMon it's used and it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Chances are the answer is going to be along the lines of _this is not supported_, but please post your actual code.

Comment: Using * only works in Perfmon.exe, it adds multiple counters.  You have to pick a *specific* network interface instance in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, let's call them an answer to my question. I'll reformulate my question and post it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is in your question: you want to create *an* instance, ie. one instance. PercormanceCounter does not return a collection of counters, which would be required when you want to select with a wildcard.

to enumerate all instances, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1305159/3961759